# problem with sorting data by time from firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

i'm tryin to sort some data using `orderBy()` on flutter
it works when i try to sort by name or by anything but not working with time
this how i store data on fire store

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cars').add({
      'time ': Timestamp.now(),
      'name': name,
      'phone': mobile,});
```

and this the code for sorthing

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('cars')
                    .orderBy('time', descending: true)
                    .snapshots(),
```

the sorting is not working even in the firebase console but when i add the timestamp from the console
directly it works and i can sort it by time but the data i added from the code is not sorted with it.

Comment: What plugin do you using for generate timestamp?

Comment: i'm new with flutter can you explain what you mean with plugin for timestamp

Comment: What is `Timestamp` class?

Comment: im using it to add time for a form data in StatefulWidget form if that what you mean

Comment: i found the problem there is a space in 'time ' ty for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.now()` like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cars').add({
      'time ': DateTime.now(),
      'name': name,
      'phone': mobile,});
```

I hope you got your answer